# Boost property tree with INI files

Tags: c++, boost

I am using Boost property tree classes to read and write MS Ini-files. One of the section name contains a literal dot as part of the string. There is no hierarchy. How can I quote this dot?

```
[system-no.1]
acq=3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only by creating paths with an alternative separator:

**[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86f59dec40879ac2)**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;

int main() {
    ptree::path_type path("system=no.1#acq", '#');

    ptree pt;
    pt.put(path, 3);

    write_ini(std::cout, pt);
}
```

Prints

```
[system=no.1]
acq=3
```

### BONUS

Because the contructor is not explicit you can abbreviate to:

```
pt.put({"system=no.1#acq", '#'}, 3);
```